# Python throws error 123 when I am trying to create a folder with a name from an array

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

I've tried to make an algorythm, which takes all the words from a txt file and makes a folder for every entry in that list. I works great, when i give it a predetermined name, but when i try to use a name from the string arry, i get:

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\Photos\Images\Ability\n'

(Ability is the first item in the list, the \n is not in the original filepath, which I print out before that.)

Here is the code I used:

```
import os
from queue import Empty
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler

with open("D:\Programming\ImageCollector\Words.txt", 'r') as Words:
    WordsList = Words.readlines()
    FolderPaths = [Empty] * len(WordsList)
    for i in range (len(FolderPaths)):
        FolderPaths[i] = os.path.join("D:\Photos\Images", WordsList[i])
        print(FolderPaths[i])
    for i in range(1):
        os.makedirs(FolderPaths[i])
```

I tried everything, parsing all the values into another arry, using it with str() and much more, but it never seems to work. But as soon as i just start putting in a predetermined string as a folder name into the first for loop, it works perfectly.

Comment: you could try `r"D:\Photos\Images"` and/or `r"D:\Programming\ImageCollector\Words.txt"`

Comment: Thanks, but didn't change it

Comment: When you read the lines in a file with `readlines()`, each line will have the newline character `\n` at the end.  You probably want to strip that off.

Comment: That makes sense, but the "\n" onely appears, after I try to make a directory, when i print out the whole path before that, i get the normal directory without the n at the end

Comment: When you print it, the `\n` would appear as just a carriage return, not as a literal `\n`.

Comment: OMG, it worked, thank you so much, I struggled like 3 hours on this problem